# C# Call function from another class

Tags: c#

I think my question is best descirbed by a code snippet:

```
class A
{
    public void FunctionToBeCalled();
}
class B
{
    public void FunctionToBeCalledAfter();
}
```

Now, after a FunctionToBeCalledAfter() call,  FunctionToBeCalled() needs to "know" it must be called. B cannot have an A member, but A can have a B member. Is there any way this can be implemented in C#?

Why i need this:
Class A is Application level on OSI stack. Classes B and C(unmentioned before) are Transport Level. C makes calls to FunctionToBeCalledAfter, and after this FunctionToBeCalled needs to be called. But sincer A is a higher level, B and C cannot depend(have a member A), i don't know how to call FunctionToBeCalled.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "FunctionToBeCalled() needs to "know" it must be called."?

Comment: "_B cannot have an A member, but A can have a B member_" -> Why? Your example seems to have been oversimplified here.

Comment: You're going to have to tell me what's wrong with `b.FunctionToBeCalledAfter(); a.FunctionToBeCalled();`

Comment: He wants to call `a.FunctionToBeCalled().FunctionToBeCalledAfter()` instead off `b.FunctionToBeCalledAfter(); a.FunctionToBeCalled();`

Comment: I have only one instance of class A in my program, but multiple B instances. Whenever a B instance calls FunctionToBeCalledAfter(), the A instance needs FunctionToBeCalled(). I don't know how to do this(or if it's possible at all) without having an A instance as a member of class B(which is a necessity). @Llama

Comment: [Singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#C#)? Then inside `FunctionToBeCalledAfter` do `A.Instance.FunctionToBeCalled()`

Comment: You could also have an event in `B` and have `B` call its event delegate at the end of `FunctionToBeCalledAfter`  Then, whenever you create a `B`, you can `b.AfterEvent += () => a.FunctionToBeCalled()`  Then `B` doesn't store `A` -- instead `B` has an `event` member and adds to the delegate to arrange for `A` to be called..

Comment: @RisteaStefan Nothing in your comment implies that `B` cannot reference `A`.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay i have edited the question, to explain why B cannot reference A.

Comment: `Class A is Application level on OSI stack. Classes B and C(unmentioned before) are Transport Level`...this doesn't obviously make any sense, unless you're writing a program which is supposed to model/simulate an OSI stack as an exercise, and there are some restrictions in place in order to preserve the integrity of the logical model? In that case maybe an event-based pattern could make sense, as Wyck suggested. But it might be better if we had a more complete and less generic/minimal example.

Comment: I am writing a program which is supposed to model/simulate an OSI stack. Classes A B and C are just a simplification of what i need to implement. IN reality, the classes are much bigger and complex. But i only need to implement a small feature, that is close to the example i presented.

Comment: Without the whole picture, guess 2 approaches can solve your problem. 1. Having a Static Class 2. Have another class (layer) which knows about these 2 classes.. hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

I see 2 ways to accomplish this, one easier but (arguably) less elegant, one a little more involved but (arguably) more elegant

1. The less elegant solution: Singleton

A Singleton pattern enforces that there can only ever be one instance of a class at any given time, this seems to line up with your description of `A` (which from here on out I'll call `Foo`, and I'll be calling `B` `Bar`). So let's implement it:

```cs
public class Foo
{
    private static Foo _instance;

    public static Foo Instance => _instance ?? (_instance = new Foo());

    // Private constructor so no one else can instantiate Foo
    private Foo() { }

    public void FunctionToBeCalled() { /* your code here */ }
}

public class Bar
{
    public void FunctionToBeCalledAfter()
    {
        // Your existing code here
        Foo.Instance.FunctionToBeCalled();
    }
}
```

Now, the problem here is if your requirements ever change and you need multiple `Foo`s, that'll be quite a refactor to implement it. Another (larger) downside is that we explicitly reference (i.e depend on) `Foo`, which isn't great and a problem if `Bar` is inside a project/ library that cannot directly reference `Foo`. Luckily solution 2 fixes those problems:

2. The more elegant solution: Events

```cs
public class Foo
{
    // We don't need Foo to be a singleton anymore
    public void FunctionToBeCalled() { /* Your code here */ }
}

public class Bar
{
    public delegate void FunctionToBeCalledAfterEventHandler();

    public event FunctionToBecalledAfterEventHandler FunctionToBeCalledAfterEvent;

    public void FunctionToBeCalledAfter()
    {
        // Your existing code here
        OnFunctionToBeCalledAfterEvent(); // Fire the event
    }

    private void OnFunctionToBeCalledAfterEvent()
    {
        FunctionToBeCalledEvent?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Now, everywhere where you're creating an instance of `Bar` you need to have a reference to `Foo` and subscribe to the event like so:

```cs
// foo = instance of class Foo
var bar = new Bar();

// The compiler is smart enough to find out that 'FunctionToBeCalledAfterEvent'
// has the same signature as 'FunctionToBeCalledAfterEvent' and can call it directly
// If this just so happens to not be case, see second way to subscribe to events
bar.FunctionToBeCalledAfterEvent += foo.FunctionToBeCalled;

// Or
bar.FunctionToBeCalledAfterEvent += () => foo.FunctionToBeCalled();
```

Events are great

Answer (score 1):

Class B can have an [event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/) that other parties can handle. At the end of `B.FunctionToBeCalledAfter` this event would be invoked. Anyone who registered for this event would then be notified. Usual boilerplate code involves one virtual method that invokes one event. It's the standard way of adding events. If there is no need for additional data in the event then `EventArgs` is used. If additional data is needed then you could replace `EventArgs` with `EventArgs<YourData>`, or as an alternative, introduce a class `XxxArgs` derived from `EventArgs` with this additional data.

```
Class B
{
    public event EventHandler FinishedFunctionToBeCalledAfter;

    protected virtual void OnFinishedFunctionToBeCalledAfter(EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler handler = FinishedFunctionToBeCalledAfter;
        handler?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    public void FunctionToBeCalledAfter()
    {
        ...

        OnFinishedFunctionToBeCalledAfter(EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Now when class A gets a hold of an object of class B it would add its event handler to it:

```
class A
{
    public void FunctionToBeCalled();

    public void FinishedFunctionToBeCalledAfter(object source, EventArgs e);

    public void IntroduceObject(B b)
    {
        b.FinishedFunctionToBeCalledAfter += FinishedFunctionToBeCalledAfter;
    }
}
```

When this object `b` of class `B` should end its life class `A` must know about it so that it can remove its event handler:

```
b.FinishedFunctionToBeCalledAfter -= FinishedFunctionToBeCalledAfter;
```